# How to access arguments of one method in another method?

Tags: java, jdeveloper

/*
  Program for salary incrementation
*/

```
import java.util.*;
class Increment
 {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 void getdata(String n, double d, int a)
 {
    System.out.print("Enter name of employee ");
    n = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter current salary ");
    d = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter age");
    a = sc.nextInt();
 }

void calculate()
 {
    if(a>=56)
      {
        d = d+(20/100);
       }
    if(a>45&&a<56)
      {
        d = d+(15/100);
      }
    if(a<=45)
      {
        d = d+(10/100);
      }
 }

void display()
 {
    System.out.println("Name \t Age \t Basic ");
    System.out.print(n +"\t"+ d + "\t" + a);
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Increment i = new Increment();
    i.getdata();
    i.calculate();
    i.display();
    }
  }
```

How can I use values of n, d and a in calculate() method?
Please help me if you find any other mistake!

Comment: The course, tutorial, or book you're working through will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. I suggest reviewing your course materials, class notes, the book chapter, etc. It will have a much more thorough explanation than answers here are likely to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You have `getdata` *return* the information (as an object with private fields and getters [at least] for them), and then you pass that object into `calculate` and have `calculate` use the getters to get the values. (Similarly, this is how you would get information from `calculate` into `display`.)

You could also make them fields in `Increment`, but that makes `Increment` stateful (prior to calling `getdata`, it doesn't have the necessary information), which is generally best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to have instance variables, so you can use them in methods

```
class Increment
  {
String n; double d; int a;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     void getdata()
     {
        System.out.print("Enter name of employee ");
        n = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter current salary ");
        d = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        a = sc.nextInt();
     }

    void calculate()
     {
        if(a>=56)
          {
            d = d+(20/100);
           }
        if(a>45&&a<56)
          {
            d = d+(15/100);
          }
        if(a<=45)
          {
            d = d+(10/100);
          }
     }

    void display()
     {
        System.out.println("Name \t Age \t Basic ");
        System.out.print(n +"\t"+ d + "\t" + a);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Increment i = new Increment();
        i.getdata();
        i.calculate();
        i.display();
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the variables you are using

```
String n;
double d;
int a;
```

Also the main put it in another class.
In method "calculate" use the switch